Can Superman cut himself with his heat vision?
Can Superman cut himself with his heat vision?
Can Superman cut an alternate version of himself (e.g. clone, parallel universe) using his heat vision?

Obviously not, since we never see him with shaving burns.

Maybe he can control the power of its heat vision from low to very high.

Multiple examples of him cutting himself with his heat vision; https://www.quora.com/Can-Superman-cut-himself-with-his-heat-vision

@Valorum I understand from there that the answer is yes.

@Triceratops - It's pretty inconsistent though. Sometimes he can, sometimes he can't. It depends on the writer

In Justice League (2001), in episode A Better World, an alternate Superman used his heat vision to lobotomise Doomsday, which implies going through the skin and the bones then damaging part of the brain.



Considering the fact Doomsday is a clone with Kryptonian DNA, we can assume that Superman himself could equally be affected similarly by another Kryptonian heat vision.
